# Cisco ASA 5505: Created a faulty NAT rule. Can't reach the ASA

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-asa

I was trying to create a NAT rule to reach my internal web server from inside the LAN.
Something must have gone wrong. Now when i try to reach the ASA through `https://192.168.1.1` 
the response is from the web server (192.168.1.5), so I can't reach the ASA's configuration through the web interface.
What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Console cable, or connect a laptop with a static 192.168.1.2 directly to the LAN port of the ASA.  Or if you didn't save the running config to startup, simply reboot the ASA.

Comment: If I use a Console Cable, what is the command to delete an existing NAT rule?

Comment: What's the existing NAT rule you wish to remove?  Are you replacing it with something else?  You can disable/inactivate it depending on the ASA version (see here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/nat_rules.html).  Did you actually save the running config to startup?  If not you can copy the startup to the running config and be back where you started today.